# Can't compile java project when I am using DSL json serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, dsl

I have googled on this. But doesn't get any result.

I am using jdk 8 of java.
When I am going to compile this code snippet. I get this error.

this is ResponseBody class.

```
public class ResponseBody {
    private String message;

    public ResponseBody(){
        this.message = null;
    }
    
    
    public ResponseBody(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            DslJson dslJson = new DslJson<>();
            // ResponseBody is class with one property 'message'
            ResponseBody responseBody = new ResponseBody();
            responseBody.setMessage("hello saiful");


            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            dslJson.serialize(responseBody, outputStream);
            byte[] serializedObject = outputStream.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("Object serialized to byte array");

            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedObject);
            responseBody = (ResponseBody) dslJson.deserialize(ResponseBody.class, inputStream);
            System.out.println("Object deserialized to byte array: "+responseBody.toString());

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

in pom.xml, I have added this dependency for DSL json

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.dslplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>dsl-json-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

compilation error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Mono is required to run DSL compiler. Mono not detected or specified.
[ERROR] DSL compilation error
  Unable to setup DSL-JSON processing environment. Specify dsljson.loglevel=DEBUG for more information.
```

Comment: what dependency for ResponseBody is required?

Comment: can you provide response body class?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java jdk 8. then add this dependency in pom.xml instead of given dsl dependency

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dslplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>dsl-json-java8</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
```